# APACHE OFFICE installation

Tags: apache2, libreoffice

why libre office need to be uninstalled while installing apache office. I am finding libre
office  too slow when hd images are loaded for project work, the pages moves in a very slow motion and if give command it takes 2-3 sec to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

> why libre office need to be uninstalled while installing apache office.

Libreoffice (LO) and Apache OpenOffice (OO) are basically the same software.  If you want both you need to install one of the 2 from source.

To understand why you need to know a bit of the history of both...

Sun Microsystems was bought by Oracle in 2011. Oracle then renamed the (proprietary) StarOffice office suite to Oracle Open Office and then killed the software.

Most of the volunteers left the project and formed LibreOffice. So LibreOffice is a fork of OpenOffice.org and is built on the original OpenOffice.org code base.

Ubuntu (and most of the other Linux systems) started using LibreOffice.

After a while Oracle gave the OpenOffice.org trademarks and code to the Apache Software Foundation. Apache OpenOffice is now being developed under the Apache license.

---

**Any differences?**

- different default theme
- OpenOffice starts with a sidebar. LibreOffice does not; you need to enable it.
- LibreOffice has a status bar at the bottom of the window with live-updating word count. OpenOffice does not. You need to select *Tools* -> *Word Count* to view the word count and it will not update nor show itself automatically.
- LibreOffice has support for font embedding.

You can see here that these are just minor minor minor details. Both suites still use the same code base with the same names for modules, libraries and everything else. So they cannot exist on the same machine using the same installation tool.

If you want you can install LibreOffice and OpenOffice both, but 1 of these needs to be built from source so you can install it on another location (like in /opt).

**How about the license?**

The Apache OpenOffice project uses the Apache License, while the LibreOffice project uses a dual LGPLv3 / MPL license. So LibreOffice can take OpenOffice’s code and incorporate it into LibreOffice.

The two different licenses only allow a one-way transfer of code. LibreOffice can add code from OpenOffice. OpenOffice can not incorporate code from LibreOffice. This is the result of the different licenses the projects chose.

This should explain why you can not use both at the same time using the normal installation tools.

Now for your problem. It is too vague, so I would suggest to post a new one with details and including some information about what you seem to claim to be slow.

> the pages moves in a very slow motion and if give command it takes 2-3 sec to execute it.

- if LibreOffice is slow so will OpenOffice be. There is not a lot difference between them. Nothing to make it slow. In case removing LibreOfice and installing OpenOffice makes it quick, re-installing LibreOffice will make it quick again too. If NOT this is a BUG and should be reported so it can be fixed.
- you assume it is LibreOffice that is slow. But it could also be your system that is not fast enough. There is no information about your system in your post, so there is nothing to go on.

Answer (score 0):

If performance issues are the main problem, you should first try to tackle them directly: In LibreOffice Writer, go to Menu `Tools` -> `Options` -> `LibreOffice` -> `View`, and check if `Hardware acceleration` is enabled and `Anti-Aliasing` is disabled.

If this isn't sufficient, think about hiding the hi-res pictures when working with a writer document. Go to Menu `Tools` -> `Options` -> `LibreOffice Writer` -> `View`, and disabled "`Graphics and objects`" under "`Display`".

Comment: Thanx a lot for the help, When i disable the Graphics and objects the pages moves smoothly as in word, but i need to work with the images , like under the image i have to add descritpion and always i cannot hide hig res pictures, any other alternative Also Antiliasing was enable. As per your suggestion i disabled it. Still no improvement

Comment: Hmm - in any case, as Rinzwind already wrote, you shouldn't expect a big performance boost by replacing LO by Apache OpenOffice. You may give it a try, but may DTP software like Scribus may do a better job on a high-res picture-rich document. Another idea may be to toggle displaying the images using a macro and a keyboard shortcut.